# Body for pure virtual function in C++17?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I tried to write an pure virtual function in Base class, and i give it an body **near the definition** as it shown in the code bellow, as I know i should get an compile error, But everything worked fine. Is it something new that come with C++17 ? (I used visual studio 2017)

```
class Base {
public:
virtual void virtual_func() { std::cout << "This a virtual function from BASE" << std::endl; };
virtual void pure_func() = 0 { std::cout << "This a PURE virtual function from BASE" << std::endl; };
};
```

Thanks

Comment: "I know i should get an compile error" - why?  It's perfectly legal to implement pure virtual  functions.

Comment: The standard doesn't allow this, but VS (or more accurately, Microsoft's compiler) does. To conform, you need separate the definition from the declaration.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth  I don't think so.  It can't compile at C++14. http://ideone.com/EISKsp

Comment: @NeilButterworth; It's perfectly legal to implement them, but the definition has to be separate.

Comment: @Jerry Yep, forgot that. Do you know of any compelling technical reason why the definition has to be separate?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: No, not to my knowledge.

Comment: Standard says - _A virtual function declared in a class shall be defined, or declared pure in that class, **or both**_. Since... Ever? Nothing to do with C++17 actually.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Just speculation, but I would guess it's to make pure virtual function more noticeable.  If they could be defined where they're declared, then it's possible that people won't notice that they're pure virtual, especially in cases where the definition is short enough to fit on a single line (such as a simple `return x;`).  Separating any definition from the declaration, on the other hand, guarantees that `= 0` will always be the end of the line, making it easier to notice.

Comment: (Barring weirdness like `virtual int i() = 0, j();`, at least.)

Answer (score 4):

The pure virtual cannot be used together with a definition.  This was true in C++11, and in C++14:

> **10.4/2:**...
>   [ Note: A function declaration cannot provide both a pure-specifier
>   and a definition — end note ] [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct C {
> virtual void f() = 0 { }; // ill-formed
> };
> ```

The same statement (under section 13.4/2 this time) is still true for C++17 (N4659).

So if your compiler accept this code, it's certainly a bug ([gcc 7.1 doesesn't](https://godbolt.org/g/FctQJj))

Comment: FYI, I reported this bug to Microsoft: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/187888/msvc-incorrectly-allows-pure-virtual-function-defi.html